# Importación de ficheros json en modelos con definición de campos mediante Django admin

Tags: python, json, django, django-admin

Estoy intentando importar mediante parseo ficheros de datos en json a modelos de datos Django.

He definido una tabla con las "entidades" donde se sube el fichero json con los datos.

Mediante las acciones de Django en admin pretendo subir el fichero, por ejemplo "Artículos", lanzo la acción, carga el json y parsea o relaciona cada campo importando los datos en los modelos.

```
class Entidad(TimeStampedModel):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    archivo = models.FileField(upload_to="importaciones/entidades/", help_text="Fichero formato *.json")
```

Otra tabla "relaciones" donde se indica el campo "origen" (en el json) campo "destino" del modelo:

```
class Relacion(TimeStampedModel):
   entidad = models.ForeignKey("importaciones.Entidad", related_name="relaciones", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   origen = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="Nombre del campo de la columna del fichero.")
   destino = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="Nombre del campo de la base de datos.")
   modelo = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="Nombre tabla de datos.")
```

Creo en el admin TabularInline:

```
class RelacionInline(admin.TabularInline):
   model = Relacion


class EntidadAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   inlines = [
    RelacionInline,
   ]
   actions = ['importar_datos',]


def importar_datos(self, request, queryset):
    for entidad in queryset:
        with open(entidad.archivo.path) as f:
            data = json.load(f)
            importa(data, entidad.relaciones)

    self.message_user(request, "Se ha importado xxx")


importar_datos.short_description = "Importar datos seleccionado(s)"

admin.site.register(Entidad, EntidadAdmin)
```

Ejemplo del fichero json. Hay que destacar que hay tablas relacionadas:

```
{
 "root": {
 "Products": [
  {
    "supplierCode": "34523",
    "date": "2019-04-13",
    "Product": [
      {
        "id": "789874",
        "References": {
          "Reference": [
            {
              "RefType": "GENERICO",
              "RefCode": "9879879787"
            },
            {
              "RefType": "EAN_UMV",
              "RefCode": "8000115115115"
            }
          ]
        },
        "Features": {
          "Feature": [
            {
              "FeatureCode": "1",
              "FeatureName": "Marca",
              "ValueCode": "402",
              "Value": "Nike"
            },
            {
              "FeatureCode": "2",
              "FeatureName": "Tipo",
              "ValueCode": "63",
              "Value": "Trail"
            },
            {
              "FeatureCode": "369",
              "FeatureName": "Estuche",
              "ValueCode": "15",
              "Value": "Carton"
            },
            {
              "FeatureCode": "63",
              "FeatureName": "Forma",
              "ValueCode": "23",
              "Value": "Hexagonal"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
     ]
     }
    ]
   }
  }
```

Mediante recursividad recorre el fichero con la intención de relacionar cada campo para luego importar los valores en el modelo, pero no sé si así se puede hacer, de momento creo que no:

```
def importa(obj, key, relaciones):
   arr = []
   diccionario = None
   valores = {}
   lista = ""
   diccionario = ""

   def extract(obj, arr):
      lista = ""
      diccionario = ""
      id = ""
      i = 0
      if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for k, v in obj.items():
            if k == "id":
                if id != k and id != None:
                    id = v
                    #print("cambio articulo ---",k, v)


            if isinstance(v, dict):
                #print("dict", k)
                diccionario = k
                extract(v, arr)

            if isinstance(v, list):
                lista = k
                extract(v, arr)


            elemento = relaciones.filter(origen=k).first()
            if elemento:
                valores[elemento.modelo + "." + elemento.destino] = v + " en: " + key


    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        for item in obj:
            extract(item, arr)
    return arr

results = extract(obj, arr)
return valores
```

Veo que de esta manera no lo voy a conseguir, ¿alguna sugerencia?